# Custom strip() in python using regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm doing my own function working same as `strip()`.

```
def strip(string, chars = None):
        if chars == None:
        regexOne = re.compile(r'(\w+(\s\w+)*)')
        mo = regexOne.search(string)
        return mo.group()
    else:
        regexTwo = re.compile(r'([' + chars + ']*)(.*?)([' + chars + ']*)$')
        mo = regexTwo.search(string)
        return mo.group(2)
```

Actually it works but I cannot understand why I have to put `$` at the end of regexTwo, it works only if it is present, without it group2 is empty. I know that it means end of the string but I don't know why it is so important in this regex.

Comment: What pattern are you matching with regexTwo ?

Comment: it can be anything, the result is the same, lets say string is ThePythonThe and chars is The

Answer (score 0):

The `$` at the end of the pattern tells the match must happen until the end of the string.

Actually, try this string with your function

```
s1 = "  ABC   DEF GHI   "
def strip(string, chars = None):
  if chars == None:
    regexOne = re.compile(r'(\w+(\s\w+)*)')
    mo = regexOne.search(string)
    return mo.group()
  else:
    regexTwo = re.compile(r'([' + chars + ']*)(.*?)([' + chars + ']*)$')
    mo = regexTwo.search(string)
    return mo.group(2)

print strip( s1 )
print s1.strip()
```

This prints

```
ABC
ABC   DEF GHI
```

The two results are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Without the `$`, your regular expression can validly match 0 characters for any of the three groups.

The first group uses `*` which is greedy so any characters that can be consumed will be.

The second group uses `*?` which is non-greedy so if 0 characters can be consumed, 0 characters will be consumed.  That's the root of your problem there.

Using your example:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'([The]*)(.*?)([The]*)', 'ThePythonThe').groups()
('The', '', '')
```

This will consume `The` in the first group.  Then nothing will be consumed in the second group because `*?` is non-greedy so it will attempt to consume nothing and succeed when the third group finds that it can also match nothing validly.

With the `$`, group 3 has to end at the end of the string and group 2 is as small as possible still because it's non-greedy:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'([The]*)(.*?)([The]*)$', 'ThePythonThe').groups()
('The', 'Python', 'The')
```

If that `*?` was changed to a `*`, group 2 would consume all the characters possible due to greediness and group 3 would never have any characters:

```
>>> re.search(r'([The]*)(.*)([The]*)$', 'ThePythonThe').groups()
('The', 'PythonThe', '')
```

For correctness, you'll need the `$` at the end, but I'd also recommend a `^` at the beginning for clarity (that `^` makes the intent very clear).